# Why can i not use my filtered Dataframe in a for-loop?

Tags: python

I've a problem with a similar code of mine. I've tried to filter Data from another cv file for my pass map. When I use the original data from:

```
dat_fbjk = pd.read_csv("...", sep = ';')
```

and plot it like:

```
for x in range(len(dat_fbjk['x'])):
plt.plot((dat_fbjk['x'][x],dat_fbjk['endX'][x]),(dat_fbjk['y'][x],dat_fbjk['endY'][x]), color='green')
```

**it works fine**.

But if I filter the original DF like:

```
filt_1 = (dat_fbjk['type/displayName'] == 'Pass') & (dat_fbjk['teamId'] == 500)
pass_500 = dat_fbjk[filt_1]

and use the same plot with:

    df = pass_500

    for x in range(len(df['x'])):
    plt.plot((df['x'][x],df['endX'][x]),(df['y'][x],df['endY'][x]), color='green')
```

It doesn't work. I don't quite get it, bc. it's the same DF just with less input.

Edit:

I did a further analysis:

This is working:

```
print(dat_fbjk['outcomeType/displayName'][1])
```

This has an Error:

```
print(df['outcomeType/displayName'][1])
```

Error:

KeyError: 0

What is the problem?

Comment: I think, I've seen the problem. The index is still like the old DF. So bc the index starts with 18, it gets an KeyError. Is there any way to iterate through the index number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it like:

```
for x in df.index:
if df['outcomeType/displayName'][x] == 'Successful':
    plt.plot((df['x'][x],df['endX'][x]),(df['y'][x],df['endY'][x]),color='green')
    plt.scatter(df['x'][x],df['y'][x],color='green')


if df['outcomeType/displayName'][x] == 'Unsuccessful':
    plt.plot((df['x'][x],df['endX'][x]),(df['y'][x],df['endY'][x]),color='red')
    plt.scatter(df['x'][x],df['y'][x],color='red')
```

Should work now.